# PowerBi-Javascript: How do I find out the visualName value for setting a slicer?

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm attempting to use Microsoft's PowerBi-Javascript library to embed a report in a webpage. I want to apply a slicer on load, that depends on the actual page I'm on (so can't be done by defaults on the report).

The library wiki gives a way to do this by setting slicers in the config passed to the embed function. The slicer object looks something like this (from the documentation https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Slicers):

```
interface ISlicer {
  // Selects a slicer to change.
  selector: SlicerSelector;

 // A new state of the slicer
 state: ISlicerState;
}

interface ISlicerSelector {
  $schema: string;
  visualName: string;
}
```

I'm happy with setting up the state using the filtering examples given, but I'm having problems finding the visualName for the selector - I can't see it in the interface (on viewing or editing), and I've tried using the names/headers etc I can see, none of which work.

How do I find out and/or set what this visualName is?

Answer (score 0):

I've not found a way in the UI to see this. Hopefully there is a better way than the below, but this does work.

However, it is possible to find out using the api, or using this library if you're able to mess around running some code locally.

In my case, I found out by (while developing locally) finding the page and then the visuals that were displaying once the report had rendered, logging the data to the console, and identifying which visual was the one I wanted.

Something like:

```
report.on('rendered', () => {
        report.getPages().then(pages => {
            pages[0].getVisuals().then(visuals => console.log(visuals))
        });
    });
```

Where in this case I only cared about the first page.

This then logged some data to the console about each visual, including co-ordinate values and visualName, so I was able to identify the one I was interested in and see its visualName property.

Confusingly, the visualName property looks more like an id (although not a guid).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Visual Title (not the Slicer Title) on the slicer under General > Title > Text.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gklUF.png)

Then, you can find the slicer using the `visual.title` property.

For example,

```
report.on('rendered', () => {
    report.getPages().then(pages => {
        pages[0].getVisuals().then(visuals => console.log(
            visuals.find(visual => visual.title === "MySlicer")
        );
    });
});
```